# CKEditor - Save Multiple contenteditable - Divs Stripped Out

Tags: plugins, youtube, ckeditor

I have an inline web page editor which allows the user to edit the content (specified in the div id='saveableContent') for each page.

I'm using CKEditor 4.2.1 along with the Youtube plugin: https://github.com/fonini/ckeditor-youtube-plugin

The inline editor has multiple contenteditable='true' divs for the parts of the page that can be editable, much like following: the http://nightly.ckeditor.com/14-01-03-07-05/standard/samples/inlineall.html

I will post an example with only one contenteditable div but note that there may be multiple on a page.
Before I was using the YouTube plugin, I would simply save the entire content by getting:

```
$('#saveableContent').html();
```

which kept all the code intact. However, once I started using the YouTube plugin, when adding a YouTube video it displays it as an iFrame image.

```
<div aria-describedby="cke_66" title="Rich Text Editor, content" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, content" role="textbox" style="position: relative;" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" class="entry editablecontent cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders cke_focus" id="content" contenteditable="true">
<!--{cke_protected}{C}%3C!%2D%2D%20Home%20page%20heading%20%2D%2D%3E--><h2>Freight</h2>
<!--{cke_protected}{C}%3C!%2D%2D%20Para%20%2D%2D%3E-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br></p><p><span></span>
   <img class="cke_iframe" data-cke-realelement="%3Ciframe%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F3i_bsfwPE1s%22%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20height%3D%22360%22%20width%3D%22640%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E" data-cke-real-node-type="1" alt="IFrame" title="IFrame" src="http://pcbca-new.dev/ckeditor/plugins/fakeobjects/images/spacer.gif?t=D7UD" data-cke-real-element-type="iframe" data-cke-resizable="true" style="width:640px;height:360px;" align="">
   <br></p><br></div>
```

In order for it to convert to a real iFrame html, I would need to use

```
CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData();
```

Which contains the real converted iFrame code:

```
<!-- Home page heading -->
<h2>Freight</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/3i_bsfwPE1s" width="640"></iframe><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

but the problem is, it strips out all my divs that contain the contenteditable='true' so the next round the page is loaded for editing, none of the sections are editable anymore.

Sooooo.... I want to be able to maintain all the code as is ($('#saveableContent').html();) but at the same time have the iFrame image converted to a real iFrame (CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData();).

I thought maybe I can disable the automatic cleaning of the code by CKEditor so I tried

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

But that didn't work.

What can I do to ensure that all iFrame images on the page are converted to the real iFrame code while at the same time the div's are maintained with all it's attributes?

Answer (score 0):

While CKEditor protects iframes, scripts videos and stuff while running, I see several solutions of your problem, depending on your needs:

1. The "right way": Don't save the contents of `#saveableContent` as a whole but iterate over `CKEDITOR.instances` and collect `editor.getData()`. Then, when rendering the page de-serialize that HTML (quite likely an array of editor contents) back into editors in `#saveableContent` (`editor.setData( html )`). This way `#saveableContent` is never stored in database and you gain control over your HTML: you can discard/modify/alter contents of a particular editor if you need.
2. The "somewhat right way": Iterate over `CKEDITOR.instances` and collect `editor.getData()`. Concatenate it with a string `'<div id="saveableContent">' + ... + '</div>'`. Note that your data is not structured any longer.
3. The "nasty way": Iterate over `CKEDITOR.instances` and call `editor.destroy()` before saving the contents of `#saveableContent`. Note that it may be no solution for you if you want to keep editors alive (i.e. "auto-save").